# Laravel 5.4 validator not seeing input field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

So I'm trying to setup validation using the `Validator` facade. For some strange reason, the validator is not seeing one of the input fields though it's present in the request. Here's the validation code:

```
        $rules = [
            'name'          => 'required',
            'resource_type' => 'required',
            'semester'      => 'required',
            'file'          => 'required|max:8196'
        ];
        $messages = [
            'name.required' => 'The name field is required',
            'semester.required' => 'The semester field is required',
            'resource_type.required' => 'The resource_type field is required',
            'file.required' => 'The file field is required',
            'file.max' => 'The max file size is 8196 kilobytes',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->input(), $rules, $messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->messages(), 422);
        }
```

And here's the test I'm running:

```
$file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('file.pdf', 512);
    $response = $this->json( "POST", 'api/v2/papers', [
        "name"          => $paper->name,
        "semester"      => $paper->semester,
        "resource_type" => $paper->resource_type,
        "file"          => $file,
    ] )->assertSuccessful();
```

When I print the value of `$response->content()` I get

`{"file":["The file field is required"]}`

The file field is present so I'm not sure what is really going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your content type with a _file_ is no json, you've to test a normal request with content type _multipart/formdata_

Comment: @Matz According to the official laravel documentation, one should be able to post a file with the json method.

Comment: what you are getting in `$file` ?

Comment: @user2486 It's a dummy file generated by the fake class

Comment: Nice, never seen that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `$request->input()`, it does not include files.

Use `$request->all()`